# Matching a Junction makes Match immutable

Tags: regex, match, raku, junction

Just for the heck of it, I am trying to match a [junction](https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction) against a regex with the `m//` [operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Match_syntax) in raku (search for `Explicit topic match` on that page).

In the `perl6` REPL:

```
> any('a','b') ~~ m/./
False
```

Afterwards, no matter how I call `m//` I get an immutable-match complaint:

```
> 'x' ~~ m/./
Cannot modify an immutable Match (｢a｣)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

**Question**

What is happening behind the scenes here?

**Discussion**

The problem seems to stem from the fact that the `$/` [special variable](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/$$SOLIDUS) is set to the junction

```
any(｢a｣, ｢b｣)
```

after the junction match, and it seems to be that `｢a｣` in the junction that's raising the complaint.

As soon as I do anything that changes `$/` to something else, functionality is restored:

```
> $/=Any
(Any)
> 'x' ~~ m/./
｢x｣
```

or

```
> 'x' ~~ /./
｢x｣
> 'x' ~~ m/./
｢x｣
```

(so matching with `//` first, so as to change `$/`, and *then* match with `m//`).

**Clarification**

I am not trying to "achieve" anything beyond what the question's asking: I simply want to understand this behavior.

**Edit**

For cross-reference purposes, this is now also a `rakudo` [github issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4002), as suggested by @jjmerelo.

Comment: It's probably a bug, but the actual mechanism for this bug would have to be researched.

Comment: Thanks; at least I'm not the only one baffled by this :). On a related note, I was also surprised by the original match `any('a','b') ~~ m/./` returning `False`; I'd definitely expect a `True` there..

Comment: i was preparing an answer, but you have answered exactly the same in your edit while I was doing it. The problem seems to be that $/ is not assigned using the normal mechanism, but a mechanism that finds the immutable 'a'. I would have to go into the source to find it out. But this is definitely an issue, it would be nice if you raised it in the Rakudo repo.

Comment: @jjmerelo: thank you, I'll do that soon (raise an issue).

Comment: re `False`. The `m/.../` is an "Explicit topic match". It matches against `$_`. What value is `$_` set to? The sub-expression `m/.../` is being evaluated within an outer expression, which is `LHS ~~ RHS`. And that's the smart match operator which temporarily binds `$_` to the LHS for the duration of evaluating the RHS and then applying the `.ACCEPT` method to the result of that evaluation. So it successfully matches `any('a','b')` producing a junction of match objects `any(｢a｣, ｢b｣)`. Then the smart match itself evaluates. And `any('a','b') ~~ any(｢a｣, ｢b｣)` is (appropriately I think) `False`.

Comment: Golfed. `$/ = any 42; say 'x' ~~ m/./` yields `Cannot modify an immutable...`.

Comment: @raiph Thanks for that; I've replied more fully [on github](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4002).

Comment: This was a bug: fixed with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/5b3691817a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The side issue of whether the match should return `False` or `True` is settled, I think, in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650122/matching-a-junction-makes-match-immutable-in-raku?noredirect=1#comment114314811_64650122) by @raiph.

On the other hand, the main problem of receiving the `immutable Match` error [was](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4002), it seems, a bug, with [a commit](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/5b3691817a) that at least on my system fixes it.

So the problem was (as per the commit message) that regex match objects were not expected to be junctions.

Comment: "regex match objects were not expected to be junctions". Just to clarify, it's limited to just match objects assigned/bound to `$/` (other scenarios involving match objects being junctions should in theory work, modulo other bugs) when combined with 13 private/internal methods of the `Str` class (other methods should in theory work with `$/`, modulo other bugs).

Comment: The problem was not really that they were not expected to be Junctions.  The problem was some Match internals processing that passed the `$/` container around for assignment, but which did *not* have a `Mu` constraint.  This caused the assignment to be tried to *each* of the eigenstates of the Junction and fail on the first( because eigenstates are immutable) instead of assigning to the container that contained the Junction (and thus replacing it).  https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/5b3691817a fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

The following may all be poppycock. But I'm going to publish my immediate reaction, eat dessert, then explore further. :)

## Code that works

```
say any('a','b') ~~ /./; # False
say 'x' ~~ /./;          # ｢x｣
```

The difference? I dropped the `m`s.

## Why the difference?

They have different meanings.

What you presumably meant in these cases was to do regex matching of the regexes on the RHS of `~~` against the values on the LHS of `~~`.

But I think what you've actually written is sub-expressions on the RHS of the `~~` that first do a regex match *against `$_`*, and then a *subsequent* match (just a *smart match*, not a *regex match*) of the *result* of the preceding regex match (i.e. a match object or `Nil`) against the values on the LHS of the `~~`.

I've yet to explore why you get the immutable stuff but I think the above is a first step. I'll delete this answer later if it turns out to be nonsense. :)

Comment: Thanks; for clarification, I know `'x' ~~ /./` (no `m`) works: I mention this in the post, where I write that running that *first* resets `$/` and "unblocks" `'x' ~~ m/./` as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now I've eaten my dessert. :) Deleting...

Comment: Now everything's been sorted out, I think it makes sense to undelete this. After all, my analysis, as far as it went, was right, and might be helpful to later readers. In summary, don't write `foo ~~ m/bar/`, because it's not going to do anything sensible.